# AttributeError: '_process_plot_var_args' object has no attribute 'get_next_color'

Tags: python, statistics, survival-analysis, lifelines

I have tried to run the following code. but it gives an argument required error in lifelines/plotting.py file. i can't fix it .

```
import pandas as pd
from lifelines.datasets import  load_dd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = load_dd()

print data.sample(6)

from lifelines import KaplanMeierFitter
kmf = KaplanMeierFitter()

T = data["duration"]
E = data["observed"]
kmf.fit(T, event_observed=E)
kmf.survival_function_.plot()
plt.title('Survival function of political regimes');
kmf.plot()
plt.show()
```

but it gives the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/rabindra/PycharmProjects/SurvivalAnalysis/sources/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    kmf.plot()   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lifelines/plotting.py", line 331, in plot
    set_kwargs_color(kwargs)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lifelines/plotting.py", line 223, in set_kwargs_color
    kwargs["ax"]._get_lines.get_next_color()) AttributeError: '_process_plot_var_args' object has no attribute 'get_next_color'
```

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue.
Upgraded *lifelines* to 0.14.0 and *matplotlib* to 2.2.2 and it works.

Answer (score 1):

you can also refer [here](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/1763)

> Roll back matplotlib to 3.7, or use the development version of librosa from the GitHub repo.

This is working fine for python versions >3.9

Answer (score 0):

Rolled back matplotlib version to 3.7 and my librosa plots are now showing